# Dialog popup jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a code to open a dialog:

```
<p><a href="ShopItems/Rotax125MicroMax.html" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">Rotax 125 Micro Max</a></p>
```

And a page, which is the dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Paraugs Karting.lv</title>
<script src="../../js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" data-url="Rotax125MicroMax.html">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Rotax 125 Micro Max</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <img id="motor" alt="motor" src="125MicroMaxMY11.jpeg" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Is there any way to make dialog re-size itself by the content?**

Example:

[image: Dialog]

I want my dialog to end on the red line, programmly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dialog is not part of the content but sits on top of the screen. You would need a way to calculate the total height of your page under the dialog and know the height of the content being displayed. Then you would need to adjust the height on the dialog possibly Pageload and then change the height of the outer div ui-dialog i believe to the height you calculated.

It's not an "easy" novice task. Alternately, you may try to set the dialog to auto size to the content. By default though dialogs are much smaller than what you are showing by your red line. You may have a DIV open, or maybe you might have extra code or height in the dialog page.

A great way to see what is happening where is to pull up your site in CHROMe and use firebug to find the dialog and try changing the values manually to see what happens.